# Does this code pool SQL connections?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, system.data

I'm using Essential.Logging's SQL logger. I looked at the [source of the library here](http://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3e11e4ac6474#Essential.Diagnostics/Diagnostics/SqlDatabaseTraceListener.cs) and saw (at the end)

Everytime you want to log to SQL:

```
using (var connection = DbProviderFactoryExtensions.CreateConnection(dbFactory, connectionSettings.ConnectionString))
{
    using (var command = DbProviderFactoryExtensions.CreateCommand(dbFactory, CommandText, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(DbProviderFactoryExtensions.CreateParameter(dbFactory, "@ApplicationName", ApplicationName != null ? (object)ApplicationName : DBNull.Value));
        // ..snip..
        command.Parameters.Add(DbProviderFactoryExtensions.CreateParameter(dbFactory, "@Data", dataString != null ? (object)dataString : DBNull.Value));

        connection.Open(); // <====
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

The helper function right on the top of the using statement is

```
public static DbConnection CreateConnection(DbProviderFactory dbFactory, string connectionString)
{
    if (dbFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dbFactory");

    var connection = dbFactory.CreateConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    return connection;
}
```

Question:

1. Is it opening (and closing) the connection to the SQL server everytime it does that? I assume it would be more efficient to pool the connection to the SQL server, right?
2. If I were to replace that with Entity Framework 5.0 (with a `using (var db = new myDbContext()) { }` ) would that result in connection pooling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it opening (and closing) the connection to the SQL server everytime it does that? I assume it would be more efficient to pool the connection to the SQL server, right?

Yes. And no. It is calling `Close()` by way of `Dispose()`, but it's actually pooling the connections for you in the background, assuming you have not set any properties in the connection string that disallow pooling. *You don't do anything for this;* just open as late as possible, and close as soon as possible, and let ADO.NET do its thing.

> If I were to replace that with Entity Framework 5.0 (with a using (var db = new myDbContext()) { } ) would that result in connection pooling?

The DbContext also uses pooling, because it uses the regular ADO.NET behind the scenes. The code it generates generally follows the advice I gave above: Opens as late as possible, and closes as early as possible - letting ADO.NET handle pooling.

Answer (score 2):

As a supportive information to Andrew's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14064864/1313030):

Unless you disable connection pooling (by adding **Pooling=False** into your connection string), ADO.NET pools your connections. It separates connection pools according to the connection strings. If there exists a pool for the given connection string, re-uses it, otherwise creates a new connection.

Default max connection pool size is 100. But you can change pooling behavior by setting related attributes of connection string - Min Pool Size, Max Pool Size, etc.

See related [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) for how the connection pooling works and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17768/ADO-NET-Connection-Pooling-at-a-Glance) for usage details.